# Ctrl+key shortcuts are not working in a tty

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, slackware

I just installed Slackware on my laptop and all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> shortcuts are not working in a tty. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> do nothing.

I verified that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key worked with the `showkey` command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had to change my keyboard layout to `azerty` instead of `fr`.

It can be changed in **`/etc/rc.d/rc.keymap`**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Load the keyboard map.  More maps are in /usr/share/kbd/keymaps.
if [ -x /usr/bin/loadkeys ]; then
   /usr/bin/loadkeys uk.map
fi
```

`uk.map` shows that UK layout is being used here. More keyboard layouts can be found in the directory **`/usr/share/kbd/keymaps`**.

`NOTE` : This setting only applies to the console before you start the X server (GUI).

SlackWare documentation [here](https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:window_managers:keyboard_layout) explains how to set the system-wide keyboard layout ( for Slackware 13.0 , 13.1 , 13.37 and 14 ) and for particular desktop environment.